React Testing Library element.click vs fireEvent.click
What is the difference between testing the click of a button by triggering it with element.click vs fireEvent.click (RTL doc).
Here an example:
import { expect, vi } from 'vitest'
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react'

function SampleComponent({ callback }: { callback: () => void }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => callback()}>Do something</button>
    </div>
  )
}

describe('Component', () => {
  it('element.click', () => {   //Green
    const callback = vi.fn()
    render(<SampleComponent callback={callback} />)

    screen.getByRole('button').click()

    expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
  })

  it('fireEvent.click', () => { //Green as well
    const callback = vi.fn()
    render(<SampleComponent callback={callback} />)

    fireEvent.click(screen.getByRole('button'))

    expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
  })
})


Initially, I thought that the element.click was just a plain invocation of the method, and therefore I thought all the logic related to the event bubbling was missing.
But now I'm confused because even if I move the callback on the parent both scenario seems to pass.
import { expect, vi } from 'vitest'
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react'

function SampleComponent({ callback }: { callback: () => void }) {
  return (
    <div onClick={() => callback()}>
      <button>Do something</button>
    </div>
  )
}

describe('Component', () => {
  //same tests as before - Both green
})


So what's the difference, which one should be used and why?
Thx
